# power of a fraction

Tags: fractions

I am having trouble understanding where the numbers are coming from in this question.
John and Melissa wonder about the potential increase in the value of their house. Assuming a 6% appreciation per year, the formula for the value of the house after  years is [image: math formula]
, where  starts from 0.

1. Where did the 53 over 50 come from?
2. Why couldn't I just calculate 6% of 219,000 for 13,140$ a year and multiply by 3 and add that to the original value?
3. 53\50 is in parenthesis so I should divide that first? then apply the power of 3?

Comment: $\frac {53} {50} = 1.06$,  that's the same as saying an increase of $6\%$

Comment: but isn't .06 6%? or for example .10 = 10%

Comment: Which country are you from .  In the first place, I do not know why would represent 1.06 as $\frac{53}{50}$. and asking for meaning of 53 and 50?.  Quite strange!

Comment: I'm not asking the meaning of 53 over 50 I just don't understand where they got those numbers from for the formula in relation to the word problem. Also from USA

Comment: 53/50=1.06=106% of the value or 6% INCREASE from that value

Comment: Usually in these problems $1.06$ is left as a decimal. It's strange that your book converted it to a fraction.

Comment: @GFauxPas - Maybe because it's better mathematical practice to use fractions than decimals, and it's consistent with the conventions used by the book the OP is reading? It may be _uncommon_, and possibly even _unnecessary_ in this specific example, but it's more pure :-)  Plus the conversion is always fraction -> decimal, decimal is the fallen, bastard child of a fraction ;-)

Comment: Writing $\frac{53}{50}$ instead of $1.06$ is purely silly. A decimal *is* a fraction, indeed the full name is "decimal fraction."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $$\dfrac{53}{50}=1.06=\text{6% increase or 106% of the corrent value}$$
2) It is because for example, at $n=2$, the function calculates $6$% OF THE CURRENT VALUE, not the first value, $219000$. Eg at $n=2,$ it would increase by $6$%, to $\$232776$, then increase $6$% FROM $\$232776$ to $232776\times 1.06$

3) It does not matter,$$ \left( \frac{53^n}{50^n}\right)=(1.06)^n$$

Comment: That makes so much more sense now thank you. So its 106% because it is 100% of the value plus 6% more? it seems a little confusing but makes sense I suppose.

Comment: @EvilTwinkie yep! If you want to try to apply the same logic try to find the equation for a 6% decrease :)

Comment: You should get $219000(0.94)^n$